# SQL Server: select max from 2 different data columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Say, I have a structure "table_name" as follows:

```
+-----------+---------+--------------+-------+
| parent_id | file_id | created_date |Records|----- More Columns -----    
+-----------+---------+--------------+-------+
|    42     |   32    |  12/01/2016  |  254  |
|    45     |   33    |  23/04/2016  |  256  |
|    41     |   34    |  12/01/2016  |  213  |
|    42     |   35    |  18/11/2015  |  271  |
|    41     |   36    |  07/07/2016  |  198  |
|    42     |   37    |  23/04/2016  |  186  |
|    45     |   38    |  30/06/2016  |  211  |
|    42     |   39    |  29/05/2016  |  192  |
+-----------+---------+--------------+-------+
```

I want the query to return records with the last dates and the last file_id i.e the result as per the data described above should return the following:

```
+-----------+---------+--------------+-------+
| parent_id | file_id | created_date |Records|----- More Columns -----    
+-----------+---------+--------------+-------+
|    42     |   34    |  12/01/2016  |  213  |
|    42     |   35    |  18/11/2015  |  271  |
|    41     |   36    |  07/07/2016  |  198  |
|    45     |   37    |  23/04/2016  |  186  |
|    45     |   38    |  30/06/2016  |  211  |
|    42     |   39    |  29/05/2016  |  192  |
+-----------+---------+--------------+-------+
```

*NOTICE how the **file_id:32** is **NOT** considered as the latest file_id entry for **12/01/2016** is **34**, so **34** is returned and not **32**. Similarly for **file_ids: 33 & 37**, **37** is considered as **37 > 34**.*

For now I am using the sub-query thing as follows:

```
select max(file_ids) 
    from table_name
      where created_date in (
          select max(created_date) from table_name
);
```

But this approach takes a hell lot of time, like for 10k records it takes around 5-6 mins.

Comment: To clarify - are you trying to query the latest record per `file_id`?

Comment: Yes. through the inner max I'm able to figure out the latest_date, which in some cases can be same for two file_ids, and in that case when the date is found same the last file_id should be returned.

Comment: If a file_id has two rows with the same latest date, do you want both of them or just one?

Comment: @jarlh Just the one. The latest one. if there is a file_id:35 and other file_id as:36, and both have same date, then file_id:36 should be returned.

Comment: If there are two rows with same file_id (e.g.) 36, both having same latest date, but different values in the other columns, what to do?

Comment: @jarlh: The **file_id** is **unique** there will not be any such case, where both entries have same file_id.

Comment: I have edited my question, as the question has a tweak in it. Apologies to everyone who took their valuable time to answer this.

Comment: **Bold** CAPS *italic*   This is hard to read

Comment: @Paparazzi: I believe in using **BOLD** & *ITALIC*, as it helps people understand and stay focused on what statements are important and what needs to be done. But i guess that's just me! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT file_id, created_date, Records
FROM (
  SELECT file_id, created_date, Records,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY file_id
                            ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS rn
  FROM mytable ) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

The above query selects the latest record per `file_id`

Comment: You are saying that if there are two file_ids
 
**file_id:created_date ==> 35:18/01/2016 | 36:18/01/2016**

then the above thing will return 36. Right?

Comment: I have edited my question, as the question has a tweak in it. Apologies.

Comment: @HVT7 In this case you can use `PARTITION BY created_date ORDER BY file_id DESC` instead.

Comment: I have tried the above query, but it didn't work. There is also a **group by** clause according to *parent_id* field.

Comment: The following query is working fine, but taking alot of time :    select
     max(out_file.FILE_ID) as correspondence
  from
   FILES out_file cross 
  join
   PARENT_FILE_BASE parentfile
  where
   out_file.STATUS='ACTIVE'
   and parentfile.RECORD_STATUS<>'INACTIVE'
   and (
    out_file.MAILING_DATE in (
     select
      max(in_file.MAILING_DATE) 
     from
      FILES in_file cross 
     where
      in_file.STATUS='ACTIVE' 
      and parentfile.RECORD_STATUS<>'INACTIVE'
     group by
      in_file.PARENT_FILE_ID
    )
   ) 
  group by
   out_file.PARENT_FILE_ID;

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE with row_number as well.

```
Declare @Table Table(parent_id int,file_id int,created_date date,Records int)
insert into @Table values 
(42,32,' 2016/01/12 ',254)
,(45,33,'2016/04/23',256)
,(41,34,'2016/01/12',213)
,(42,35,'2015/11/18',271)
,(41,36,'2016/07/07',198)
,(42,37,'2016/04/23',186)
,(45,38,'2016/06/30',211)
,(42,39,'2016/05/29',192)

;WITH t
    AS (
        SELECT parent_id,file_id
            ,created_date
            ,records
            ,row_number() OVER (
                partition by created_date ORDER BY created_date DESC,file_id desc
                ) rn
                from @Table
        )
    SELECT parent_id,file_id
        ,created_date
        ,records
    FROM t
    WHERE rn = 1
    order by file_id
```

Comment: I have edited my question, as the question has a tweak in it. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, you might try running the query like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.created_date = (select max(t2.created_date)
                        from t t2
                        where t2.file_id = t.file_id
                       );
```

For both this and the `row_number()` version, you want an index on `t(file_id, created_date)`.  I am curious whether this might be faster in your case.

Comment: I have edited my question, as the question has a tweak in it. Apologies.